# React: Pulling a specific component from library

Tags: javascript, reactjs

How do you extract a specific React component from a library?

I'm trying to get the source code for just this component: https://rsuitejs.com/components/tree/ so that I can modify it for my specific use case.

My plan is to clone the entire library in a new React App, and then just start deleting files that I don't need. Not sure if this is the right way or if there is a more efficient way to to go about this. Any insight would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: You import explicitly what you need from the library.  No need to clone the whole thing.  You add the library as a dependency using `npm i whatever-library` and then follow the directions for importing as dictated in the docs you linked.

Comment: @zero298 Thanks for the reply! So if I wanted to extract this component and use it independently of the library, the source code would be inside the NPM package, correct?

Comment: @InquisitiveTom I would just grab it from github if you want to look at the source code (https://github.com/rsuite/rsuite) ... the only issue would be making sure you have the dependencies of the component downloaded (assuming there are any).

Comment: @infecting Ok cool, that's what I was thinking but wasn't sure if there was a better way. Thanks for the help!